# In the following Scriptures joy fills Heaven when a sinner repents, conversely is there great sorrow when an unsaved rejects salvation?

Tags: exegesis, new-testament

Matthew 23:37  KJV

> O Jerusalem, Jerusalem, thou that killest the prophets, and stonest them which are sent unto thee, how
> often would I have gathered thy children together, even as a hen gathereth her chickens under her wings,
> and ye would not!

Luke 15:7, 15:10,15:24, and 15:32

> 7 I say unto you, that likewise joy shall be in heaven over one sinner that repenteth, more than over ninety and nine just persons, which need no repentance.
>
> 10  Likewise, I say unto you, there is joy in the presence of the angels of God over one sinner that repenteth.
>
> 24  For this my son was dead, and is alive again; he was lost, and is found. And they began to be merry.
>
> 32  It was meet that we should make merry, and be glad: for this thy brother was dead, and is alive again; and was lost, and is found.

Comment: see also [Zephaniah 3:17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Zephaniah%203:17&version=ESV)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is mainly based on scripture, and I'm assuming you are looking for an answer also mainly from scripture.

There is no pleasure in the death of the wicked:

- > Have I any pleasure in the death of the wicked, declares the Lord God, and not rather that he should turn from his way and live? <sub><sub>[Ezekiel 18:23, ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/ezekial18.23)</sub></sub>
- > Say to them, As I live, declares the Lord God, I have no pleasure in the death of the wicked, but that the wicked turn from his way and live; turn back, turn back from your evil ways, for why will you die, O house of Israel? <sub><sub>[Ezekiel 33:11, ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/ezekial33.11)</sub></sub>

There may be laughter however, but not the kind that indicates joy:

- 

> He who sits in the heavens laughs;
>   the Lord holds them in derision. <sub><sub>[Psalm 2:4, ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/psalm2.4)</sub></sub>

Comment: This is true, for God is not willing (does not desire) that any should perish, but that all should come to repentance. (2 Peter 3:9.)

Comment: And [...it is pleasing in the sight of God our Savior, who desires all people to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Timothy%202&version=ESV) et al ;)